# Ordenar por data de upload após um readdir

Tags: php, data

Eu tenho este código que funciona bem, mas gostaria que as últimas imagens a serem *uploadadas* aparecessem no topo da página, em vez de aparecerem por uma ordem aparentemente '*random*'.

Não estão numa base de dados, estão só numa pasta para onde vão usando a função `move_uploaded_file(pics/....)`.

```
$myDirectory = opendir("pics");
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

closedir($myDirectory);

$indexCount = count($dirArray);

for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    $temp = explode('.', $dirArray[$index]);
    $extension = strtolower(end($temp));
    if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'tif' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'jpeg' || $extension == 'JPG'){ 
        echo '<a href="pics/' . $dirArray[$index] . '"><img class="image" src="pics/' . $dirArray[$index] . '" alt="Image"></a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com [arsort](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.arsort.php), foi criado um `dateint` com o valor gerado pelo [filemtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) e com ele o [arsort](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.arsort.php) ordenar de forma simples o array que foi criado (`$img`), sendo a data maior primeiro.

```
<?php        
     $path = "pics/";
     $dir  = opendir($path);
     $img  = array();
     $exts = array('jpg', 'png', 'tif','gif'); //extensões aceitas
     if ($dir){
         while($arq = readdir($dir)){
             $ins = explode('.', $arq);
             $out = strtolower(end($ins));
             if ($arq != '.' && $arq != '..' && in_array($out, $exts)){
                $dateint = filemtime($path.$arq); 
                array_push($img, array(
                                 'dateint' => $dateint,
                                 'name' => $arq, 
                                 'date' => date('d/m/Y H:m:s', $dateint)));
             }
         }
         if ($img && sizeof($img) > 0){
             arsort($img);       
             foreach($img as $value){                
                 echo '<p>';
                 echo '<a href="pics/'.$value['name'].'">';
                 echo '<img class="image" src="pics/'.$value['name'].'" alt="Image">';
                 echo '</a>';
                 echo '</p>';
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Obgrigado é isto mesmo, mas queria que fizesse mesmo o display das imagens (ultima parte do meu codigo), sendo que a ultima a ser uploadada ficaria no topo da page

Comment: @Miguel, foi feita edição, com a alteração de visualizar as imagens

Comment: Obgado, era isto mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar a função [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) para saber a data de gravação de cada imagem. Que pode ser usado como chave para ordenar as imagens, usando [`uksort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php), antes de serem processadas.

Ver também:

- [`fileatime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php) - data do último acesso da imagem;
- [`filectime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) - data da ultima alteração da imagem;

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php
    function mtimecmp($a, $b) 
    {
        $mt_a = filemtime($a);
        $mt_b = filemtime($b);

        if ($mt_a == $mt_b)
            return 0;
        else if ($mt_a < $mt_b)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    $imagens = glob($myDirectory."*.jpg");
    usort($imagens, "mtimecmp");
    array_reverse($imagens);

    foreach ($imagens as $imagem) 
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$imagem.'" height ="400"/><br>';
    }
?>
```

[Fonte SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16599152/1817673)